# Free drawing on canvas using fabric.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, fabricjs

I am trying to draw a free drawing on canvas using fabric.js but i am not able to free draw a like spray, circle, texture mode on my side i use this  code only the pencil mode drawing is working but when i select spray and other mode that mode drawing as pencil.

Here is my HTML [Here is fiddle ink](http://jsfiddle.net/RDqTd/)

```
            <label for="drawing-mode-selector">Mode:</label>
            <select id="drawing-mode-selector">
              <option>Pencil</option>
              <option>Circle</option>
              <option>Spray</option>
              <option>Pattern</option>

              <option>hline</option>
              <option>vline</option>
              <option>square</option>
              <option>diamond</option>
              <option>texture</option>
            </select><br>
            <label for="drawing-line-width">Line width:</label>
            <input type="range" value="30" min="0" max="150" id="drawing-            line-width"><br>
            <label for="drawing-color">Line color:</label>
            <input type="color" value="#005E7A" id="drawing-color"><br>
            <label for="drawing-shadow-width">Line shadow width:</label>
            <input type="range" value="0" min="0" max="50" id="drawing-shadow-width"><br>
          </div>
        </li>
```

Here is my script code

```
     var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas')
     var drawingModeEl = document.getElementById('drawing-mode'),
      drawingOptionsEl = document.getElementById('drawing-mode-options'),
      drawingColorEl = document.getElementById('drawing-color'),
      drawingLineWidthEl = document.getElementById('drawing-line-width'),
      drawingShadowWidth = document.getElementById('drawing-shadow-width');

     drawingModeEl.onclick = function() {
    canvas.isDrawingMode = !canvas.isDrawingMode;
    if (canvas.isDrawingMode) {
      drawingModeEl.innerHTML = 'Cancel drawing mode';
      drawingOptionsEl.style.display = '';
    }
    else {
      drawingModeEl.innerHTML = 'Enter drawing mode';
      drawingOptionsEl.style.display = 'none';
    }
  };

  canvas.on('path:created', function() {
    updateComplexity();
  });

  if (fabric.PatternBrush) {
    var vLinePatternBrush = new fabric.PatternBrush(canvas);
    vLinePatternBrush.getPatternSrc = function() {

      var patternCanvas = fabric.document.createElement('canvas');
      patternCanvas.width = patternCanvas.height = 10;
      var ctx = patternCanvas.getContext('2d');

      ctx.strokeStyle = this.color;
      ctx.lineWidth = 5;
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(0, 5);
      ctx.lineTo(10, 5);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.stroke();

      return patternCanvas;
    };

    var hLinePatternBrush = new fabric.PatternBrush(canvas);
    hLinePatternBrush.getPatternSrc = function() {

      var patternCanvas = fabric.document.createElement('canvas');
      patternCanvas.width = patternCanvas.height = 10;
      var ctx = patternCanvas.getContext('2d');

      ctx.strokeStyle = this.color;
      ctx.lineWidth = 5;
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(5, 0);
      ctx.lineTo(5, 10);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.stroke();

      return patternCanvas;
    };

    var squarePatternBrush = new fabric.PatternBrush(canvas);
    squarePatternBrush.getPatternSrc = function() {

      var squareWidth = 10, squareDistance = 2;

      var patternCanvas = fabric.document.createElement('canvas');
      patternCanvas.width = patternCanvas.height = squareWidth + squareDistance;
      var ctx = patternCanvas.getContext('2d');

      ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, squareWidth, squareWidth);

      return patternCanvas;
    };

    var diamondPatternBrush = new fabric.PatternBrush(canvas);
    diamondPatternBrush.getPatternSrc = function() {

      var squareWidth = 10, squareDistance = 5;
      var patternCanvas = fabric.document.createElement('canvas');
      var rect = new fabric.Rect({
        width: squareWidth,
        height: squareWidth,
        angle: 45,
        fill: this.color
      });

      var canvasWidth = rect.getBoundingRectWidth();

      patternCanvas.width = patternCanvas.height = canvasWidth + squareDistance;
      rect.set({ left: canvasWidth / 2, top: canvasWidth / 2 });

      var ctx = patternCanvas.getContext('2d');
      rect.render(ctx);

      return patternCanvas;
    };

    var img = new Image();
    img.src = '../assets/honey_im_subtle.png';

    var texturePatternBrush = new fabric.PatternBrush(canvas);
    texturePatternBrush.source = img;
  }

  $('#drawing-mode-selector').on('change', function() {

    if (this.value === 'hline') {
      canvas.freeDrawingBrush = vLinePatternBrush;
    }
    else if (this.value === 'vline') {
      canvas.freeDrawingBrush = hLinePatternBrush;
    }
    else if (this.value === 'square') {
      canvas.freeDrawingBrush = squarePatternBrush;
    }
    else if (this.value === 'diamond') {
      canvas.freeDrawingBrush = diamondPatternBrush;
    }
    else if (this.value === 'texture') {
      canvas.freeDrawingBrush = texturePatternBrush;
    }
    else {
      canvas.freeDrawingBrush = new fabric[this.value + 'Brush'](canvas);
    }

    if (canvas.freeDrawingBrush) {
      canvas.freeDrawingBrush.color = drawingColorEl.value;
      canvas.freeDrawingBrush.width = parseInt(drawingLineWidthEl.value, 10) || 1;
      canvas.freeDrawingBrush.shadowBlur = parseInt(drawingShadowWidth.value, 10) || 0;
    }
  });

  drawingColorEl.onchange = function() {
    canvas.freeDrawingBrush.color = drawingColorEl.value;
  };
  drawingLineWidthEl.onchange = function() {
    canvas.freeDrawingBrush.width = parseInt(drawingLineWidthEl.value, 10) || 1;
  };
  drawingShadowWidth.onchange = function() {
    canvas.freeDrawingBrush.shadowBlur = parseInt(drawingShadowWidth.value, 10) || 0;
  };

  if (canvas.freeDrawingBrush) {
    canvas.freeDrawingBrush.color = drawingColorEl.value;
    canvas.freeDrawingBrush.width = parseInt(drawingLineWidthEl.value, 10) || 1;
    canvas.freeDrawingBrush.shadowBlur = 0;
  }

  var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
document.getElementById('canvas-background-picker').onchange = function() {
    canvas.backgroundColor = this.value;
    canvas.renderAll();
  };
//end free drawing
```

See here a entire screenshot i have selected mode vline but it drawing like simple   pencil
   [image: See here a entire screenshot i have selected mode vline but it drawing like simple pencil]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've updated your jsfiddle, Now it works [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RDqTd/2/).

On your page is something wrong - look at your dev console:

```
  $('#drawing-mode-selector').on('change', function() {
  //Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'
```